# TypeError not a function for a Schema method

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, mongoose

I am currently developing a platform in order to hone and develop my skills and am trying to encrypt the password for the necessary user signup. I want to do this via a virtual field. My problem is that I can not access the self-coded `encryptPassword` method even if I turn it into a regular function.

This is my code for my `userSchema`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uuidv1 = require('uuidv1');
// uuidv1(); // ⇨ '1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed'
const crypto = require('crypto');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type:String,
        trim: true,
        required:true
    },
    email: {
        type:String,
        trim: true,
        required:true
    },
    hashed_password: {
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    salt: String, 
    created : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated: Date
});

//virtual field
userSchema.virtual('password')
.set((password) => {
    // create temporarily varibale called _password
    this._password = password;
    //generate a timestamp
    this.salt = uuidv1()
    //encryptPassword()
    this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
})
.get(function() {
    return this._password
});

//Methods

userSchema.method = {
    encryptPassword: function(password){
        if(!password) return "";
        try {
            return  crypto.createHmac('sha1', this.salt).update(password).digest('hex');
        } catch(err) {
            return ""
        }
    }
};


module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

The function in question is the `encryptPassword` function. I want to set the `hashed_password` with the `encryptPassword` function.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one piece here, missing the function name. You can add methods to the schema like this:

```
// create methods with name
userSchema.methods.encryptPassword =  function(password){
        if(!password) return "";
        try {
            return  crypto.createHmac('sha1', this.salt).update(password).digest('hex');
        } catch(err) {
            return ""
        }
    }
```

For more details, you can check the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) for creating the instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the way I structured that method. While using the mongoose way of structuring methods it worked.

```
userSchema.method({
authenticate: function(plainText){
    return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashed_password
},
encryptPassword: function(password){
    if(!password) return "";
    try {
        return  crypto.createHmac('sha1', this.salt).update(password).digest('hex');
    } catch(err) {
        return ""
    }
}
```

});